# Create view with inline function in db<>fiddle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, functions, view

I'm trying to create a view with in inline function in db<>fiddle.

*I've removed the CREATE VIEW part for now, and am just trying to run the query, just to get to the root issue.*

```
select  /*+ WITH_PLSQL */ calc from
(
with
function calculator (m number, r number) return number
is begin
return m * r;
end calculator;
select calculator(3, 2) as calc from dual
);
/
```

Source: [Inline function in a select sub query or create view](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9534452300346807610#:%7E:text=30%20am%20UTC-,This%20appears%20to%20be%20a%20client%20issue,-%2C%20which%20environment%20are)

When I run that code in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a73f5bfb341d2b29468423be18a9b49), I get an error:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What went wrong

1. That feature didn't exist in 11.2
2. You used the question SQL, not the answer SQL

## Correction

My answer is the same. Define it in the outer most `WITH` statement.

```
with
function calculator (m number, r number) return number
is begin
return m * r;
end calculator;
select calculator(3, 2) as calc from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Michael Kutz' answer:

The following seems to work in the **Oracle 18c** version of db<>fiddle.

*(I think 12c and beyond supports inline functions):*

```
create or replace view v1 as (
select /*+ WITH_PLSQL */  calc from
(
with
function calculator (m number, r number) return number
is begin
return m * r;
end calculator;
select calculator(3, 2) as calc from dual
)
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed11649c883a47ff4380022391971203)

---

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, any queries that reference that view need to have the select `/*+ WITH_PLSQL */`  hint in them:

```
select /*+ WITH_PLSQL */  
    *
from
    v1
```

That's a deal breaker for me. The system that would be using the view is a COTS system. It's not possible for me to add the hint to the queries that would be referencing the view.

Comment: In the link to the referenced source, the answer suggested that the requested statement can be used with an `INSERT` statements. (Which is what CTAS is)